# React Leaflet : Function called but not executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I try to create a function who react to a onClick event, but the function was never executed, but the fire onClick works
This is my code :

```
onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
       console.log("In onEachFeature")
    layer.on({
      onClick: this.clickToFeature.bind(this)
    });
  }
  clickToFeature(e) {
      console.log("in click")
    var layer = e.target;
    console.log("I clicked on " + layer.feature.properties.name);

 }
   render() {
      let markers = []
      let nameAccomodation = null
      // Add markers only when we received stays data
      if (this.state.dataReceived) {
        markers = this.state.stays.map((el) => {
            return(
               <Marker
                  position={[el.data.lat, el.data.lon]}
                  onpopupopen={(ev) => this.stayFocus(ev, el.id)}
                  onpopupclose={(ev) => this.stayUnfocus(ev, el.id)}>
                  <Popup>
                     {el.data.name}
                  </Popup>
               </Marker>
            )
         });
         nameAccomodation = this.state.stays.map((el) => {
            return(
               nameAccomodation=el.data.name
            )
         });
      }
```

If I replace "this.clickToFeature.bind(this)" by a console.log(""), the console print the log.
Do you know how to resolv my problem ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you show us the full component code?

Comment: @DengZhebin https://pastebin.com/BswaZPqp